# Plotting a circular bar-chart in 3d with mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to generate a 3d-plot with mathematica that arranges numbers from a dataset of any size in a full circle as 3d-bars. In this process, the values ​​of the numbers reflect the height of the bars. The following example demonstrates it very well:

```
data={1,2,3,4};
```

out=

[image: circular 3d-bar-chart]

Can this be done with mathematica? If yes, how? Maybe someone here has a quick Solution for that :) Thanks in advance. Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated**

Use `Cuboid` to draw any 3D BarChart.

```
Clear[values, n, cuboid, regs, r, pts, circle3];
values = {2.5, E, π, 4.15, 5.555, 6.45};
values = Reverse@values;
n = Length@values;
cuboid[h_] = Cuboid[{-1/2, -1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, h}];
regs = Table[
   Show[HighlightMesh[
      cuboid@h, {Style[1, {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}], 
       Style[2, None]}], 
     RegionPlot3D[cuboid@h, Mesh -> {Range[Floor[h]]}, 
      MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
      Boxed -> False, MeshStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> Pink]] // First, {h, 
    values}];
r = n;
pts = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ CirclePoints[{r, Pi}, n];
circle3[r_] = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t], -.1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Brown];
Graphics3D[{Pink, 
  MapThread[
   GeometricTransformation[#1, 
     TranslationTransform[#2]@*
      RotationTransform[π/3, {0, 0, 1}]] &, {regs, pts}], 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", circle3[r][[1]], 
  MapThread[
   Inset[Style[NumberForm[N@#1, 2], Blue, 
      20], #2 + {0, 0, #1} + {0, 0, .8}] &, {values, pts}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
values = {1, 2, 3, 4};
values = Reverse@values;
n = Length@values;
regs = ArrayMesh[{ConstantArray[{1}, #]}] & /@ values;
r = n;
pts = PadRight[#, 3] & /@ CirclePoints[{r, Pi}, n];
circle3[r_] = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t], -.1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Brown];
Graphics3D[{Pink, 
  MapThread[
   GeometricTransformation[#1, 
     TranslationTransform[#2]@*RotationTransform[π/3, {0, 0, 1}]@*
      TranslationTransform[-{1/2, 1/2, 0}]] &, {regs, pts}], 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", circle3[r][[1]], 
  MapThread[
   Inset[Style[#1, Blue, 20], #2 + {0, 0, #1} + {0, 0, 1}] &, {values,
     pts}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great solution! But Unfortunately, this function cannot work with fractions and negative numbers. And there is also no function that can be used to define the size (height and width) of the stones. I think, such a function would be very great for large sets with large numbers, otherwise it will go immeasurably in the high and breaks the frame. Maybe we can optimize that a bit, then it would be perfect! Of course, only if you have the desire and the time to do that. Thank you again for your efforts, i really appreciate that!

Comment: @Karl560 Re-write the regs by using RegionProduct can easy to do this for any real numbers, but I have not computer here :)

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but I don' t think I can do it, because my skills are too low. But if you should decide to finish the whole thing, then I would be happy to honor your work. I hope that wasn't inappropriate, but I don' t want to give the impression that I want something for free. The entire thing should help to quickly and efficiently detect anomalies in a dataset with the naked eye. And this type of diagram works very well for that, see the attached image, you can see the anomalies immediately.

https://s20.directupload.net/images/220822/iko97x6p.jpg

Comment: @Karl560 I will updated the code later after I get home.

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thank you very much!

Comment: wow, I am really impressed! That's an awesome work! Big Thanks! Is here a way to message you privately? Unfortunately, I did not find any contact options on your profile.

Comment: @Karl560  If the answer fully meets the requirements,we can accept this answer by the symbol ✔ at the left side of the answer.